# Where are mxrecords set - in the domain or the hosting?

Tags: email, dns, hosting

I have a domain name at web.com, hosting with another site, and want to setup emails through Google Suite. My memory from previous experience tells me that I should be able to set mxrecords directly inside the domain, but web.com is telling me:

> Your domain name is not pointing towards Web.com's name servers, this
>   means if you want to make any changes, you will need to access the
>   zonefile at the place where you are pointing them, as control is
>   there.

The hosting is taking place on another site. So I read the above and think this means I need to contact the guy who handles my hosting to add the records. So I do, and I get this response:

> You have to do it through web.com to change dns and add new records.
>   It is done through domain not hosting

Is someone wrong? Or am I misunderstanding how this process works?

Comment: MX records, being DNS records, are set at the DNS level.

Comment: @tadman So does this mean they would be set where the nameservers are pointing, e.g. the host? Or they are set in the same place as nameservers, e.g. the domain?

Comment: You can have your domain registered with one company (registrar) and have your DNS hosted elsewhere, but they can also be the same company. You can check which company you're using through any [WHOIS service](http://whois.domaintools.com).

Comment: @tadman So my domain is currently with web.com, but is says the registrar is http://www.register.com and the nameservers are pointing at GoDaddy. It seems like that is the only relevant information on the page. Can you help me make sense of where I would go to add mxrecords?

Comment: Sounds like you need to go to GoDaddy to set up your MX records then. Wherever the nameservers are, that's where you go to edit.

Comment: @Tylerk2 Please stop saying "mxrecords". This has no sense. You need one or multiple MX records in your zone. A zone is a collection of records in/for a domain name. There are A records, AAAA ones, NS, SOA, and many others, and MX too. The zone is served by nameservers. So inside your nameservers configuration you will need to add the MX records. So you need to ask/go to the company that handles your nameservers.